# Make an object travel along a line created by AB Points

Tags: java, vector, trigonometry

[ On my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344061/atan2-find-angle-between-two-points-360deg?noredirect=1#comment91644898_52344061) I have explained the details ]

If you observe the image below, you will notice that there's a `Bullet` object, which originates from the point `A(x1,y1)`, and the two other points which would be `B` and `C`. Now, when the `Bullet` is created, it gets the last known position of `target` and saves it. Then, it is supposed to travel to that point and further until it collides with any other object.

So, my question to you is: **How do I make the `Bullet` object travel along the line between A & B and then continues in the same path unless stopped by another block?** Imagine shooting at a target with a real gun; the bullet would travel as long as it could even if target moved itself. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of a bullet at a given time `t` travelling at some velocity `v` (which you can choose arbitrarily), we can follow these steps. I will assume that `t=0` when the bullet is fired. (you can adjust to make this a `dt` (delta time) if you want too, it makes no difference)

1. First find the (normalized) vector that will denote the direction of the bullet. This would be given by `(1 / sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)) * (x2-x1, y2-y1)`. Create this vector once for when the bullet is "fired" and do not change it, as bullets stay on a constant trajectory. (You could maybe make the vector a member of the `Bullet` class to save it, just an idea)
2. Next, multiply this by the scalar `v`. I should note that you can ignore this variable if you want as it can be accounted for in `t`, but from a physics perspective it makes intuitive sense to include.
3. Finally, to get the position, simply multiply this vector by `t` where t is some time, and then add the original point `(x1, y1)` vector to this resulting vector. (Note that all of this is just 2d kinematics, there are many online resources if you want to explore this more.

This will yield the `x` and `y` positions of the bullet at a given time `t`. Then, as you update the `x` and `y` positions, you will need to implement some collision detection function/algorithm to detect if the bullet has hit something. Since I do not really know how you organized your code I cannot give you specific advice on the best way to do this, but here are some  pointers.

First, I would recommend putting your objects that go on screen in a list/map. Also, I would recommend making your objects of simple shape (i.e. square, circle) so that it is relatively easy to check if a collision has occurred. Alternatively, you could make the collision a certain color, then  check if the color value at the position of the bullet matches this color. If it does, then you know a collision has occurred. All of these are just ideas, but there are really many more (and probably slightly better) ways of doing this.

Looking at your previous question, I notice that you try to use angles. While it is certainly a valid approach to do this, I think this solution is relatively simply to understand and avoids the trigonometric aspect of it all.

Anyways, I hope I answered your question. Leave a comment/question if you have any further inquiries about this.