# How to normalize a tensor to be in a unit sphere?

Tags: vector, pytorch, normalization

I have multiple tensors with different shapes

```py
tensor_1 = torch.tensor([[1.0, 8.0, 31.0], [3.0, 4.0, 0.0]])
tensor_2 = torch.tensor([[1.0, 8.0, 31.0, 212.1], [3.0, 11.2, 4.0, 0.0]])
```

How can I normalize/shift (not entirely sure what to call it) each of these tensors to be on an N dimensional unit circle/sphere, such that the direction/angle of each of the vectors will be the same (each tensor should have its own unit circle clearly).
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002918/what-is-the-need-for-normalizing-a-vector) on SO about how to normalize a single vector, but I'm not entirely sure if mathematically normalizing each one separately will yield the same results