# Inconsistent motion with this script

Tags: javascript, game-development

I'm trying to make a weapon in java script but the farther the mouse is from the player, the faster it shoots, apart from that, this works perfectly

on mouse position update this happens

```
trajectory.x = (mousePos.x) + (player.x)
trajectory.y = (mousePos.y) + (player.y)
```

every frame this happens

```
x = x + (trajectory.x * speed);
y = y + (trajectory.y * speed);
```

it almost works

Comment: You need to normalize the `trajectory`vector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002918/what-is-the-need-for-normalizing-a-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a constant speed irrespective of how far the mouse is from the player, divide the coordinate differences by the distance of the mouse.

I would also set a threshold: if the mouse is right on the player, it probably shouldn't move, and maybe you want a bit of tolerance -- let's say 5 pixels.

Code you could use:

```
// How far mouse should be from player before it starts to move (should be positive)
const THRESHOLD = 5; 

// ...

const diffX = mousePos.x - player.x;
const diffY = mousePos.y - player.y;
const mouseDistance = (diffX ** 2 + diffY ** 2) ** 0.5;
trajectory.x = mouseDistance < THRESHOLD ? 0 : diffX / mouseDistance;
trajectory.y = mouseDistance < THRESHOLD ? 0 : diffY / mouseDistance;
```

You may need to calibrate your `speed` variable to work well together with these "small" values for `trajectory.x` and `trajetory.y`.

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked like a charm! however, with how i programmed this so far, i needed to add the player position, not subtract it