How Should I calculate a (normalized) vector of a bullet in Visual Basic?
In visual basic X increases to the right and Y down, I'm also unsure if points can take in doubles which could be an issue.
I have attempted to calculate this in two different ways, each of which looks like they should work but produces near random results.
The first is:
Dim mousePosX As Integer
Dim mousePosY As Integer
Dim extAngle As Double
Dim intAngle As Double
Dim xVelo As Double
Dim yVelo As Double

mousePosX = e.X - 385
mousePosY = e.Y - 385

extAngle = Math.Atan(mousePosX / mousePosY) * (180 / Math.PI)
intAngle = Math.Atan(mousePosY / mousePosX) * (180 / Math.PI)

xVelo = ((5 * ((Math.Sin(extAngle) * (180 / Math.PI)))) / (Math.Sin(90) * (180 / Math.PI))) * Math.Sign(mousePosX)
yVelo = ((5 * ((Math.Sin(intAngle) * (180 / Math.PI)))) / (Math.Sin(90) * (180 / Math.PI))) * Math.Sign(mousePosY)

bullets(bulletNum).Location = New Point(385, 385) 'Resets the bullet location to the position of the player

bulletVector(bulletNum) = New Point(xVelo, yVelo)

For this method I use right triangle math on the x and y axises to try to first figure out the interior and exterior angles angles in degrees (this part may be messed up), then use the law of sines to find the length of the x and y vectors if their hypotenuse is 5 (therefore all bullets move at the same speed). This produces near random results and I see nothing wrong with it.
The second method:
Dim hypo As Double
Dim ratio As Double
Dim mousePosX As Integer
Dim mousePosY As Integer

mousePosX = e.X - 385
mousePosY = e.Y - 385

hypo = Math.Sqrt((mousePosX ^ 2) + (mousePosY ^ 2))
ratio = Math.Abs(5 / hypo)
bullets(bulletNum).Location = New Point(385, 385)

bulletVector(bulletNum) = New Point((mousePosX * ratio), (mousePosY * ratio))

For this one I just find the ratio from the real hypotenuse the the desired one of 5 then apply that ratio to the x and y lengths, it makes sense this one does not work because of the squaring involved, maybe it would make more sense to find the ratio of hypo^2 and 25 and then change the same logic for the x and y and find the square root, idk this seems like a bad way of doing it compared to the first one.
EDIT:
Dim hypo As Double
Dim mousePosX As Integer
Dim mousePosY As Integer

mousePosX = e.X - 385
mousePosY = e.Y - 385

hypo = Math.Sqrt((mousePosX ^ 2) + (mousePosY ^ 2))
bullets(bulletNum).Location = New Point(385, 385)

'bulletVector(bulletNum) = New Point(((mousePosX / hypo) * 5), ((mousePosY / hypo) * 5))
bulletVector(bulletNum) = New Point(mousePosX / Math.Abs(mousePosX), mousePosY / Math.Abs(mousePosY))

I'm trying a new method to normalize the vector (should've done this from the beginning) and it looks like even when I am just finding the quadrant as seen in finding if mousePos is negative or positive there are issues, this means the bug is likely from a misunderstanding of the VB software rather than a technical bug, why when I literally break it down to positive or negative can it still not find the correct quadrant?
SOLVED:
Dim coordinates As Point

coordinates = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
mousePosX = coordinates.X - 385
mousePosY = coordinates.Y - 385

turns out you don't need to get the mouse position from eventargs and it is better to do so this way if you have parallax background, this took me 2 weeks and made me realize why visual basic is not a game engine.

i am very unsure how you come to the conclusion that both are equivalent

I am just trying to find a way to figure out how to get the correct normalized vector with a length of 5, this means that x and y are probably always decimals and have to be calculated in this strange way, I think the first one is much more viable do you have a solution on why it just doesn't produce the right values and shoots in a random direction?

have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002918/what-is-the-need-for-normalizing-a-vector

okay after trying to normalize a vector I've realized where my issue most likely comes from.

seems like I just don't understand VB because it can't deliver neg/pos quadrants correctly even without calculations.

after more debugging e.x and e.y look at the mouse position on the picture box background which has a parallax effect and if you move the player without moving the mouse it returns a different x,y position, I need a better way to get mouse position, I'll do more research.

it is basically more complicated, every the pixel you click is depending of the dpi of the screen, which you need also take care of

I solved it I used Me.PointToClient(MousePosition) and that seemed to do the trick, now I have to figure out how the heck to delete picture boxes.
